# How can I use startcoroutine to change a variable value using while?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Outline : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float width;

    private Renderer rend;
    private float currentWidth;

    private void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        currentWidth = rend.material.GetFloat("_Outline");

        StartCoroutine(ChangeOutline());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //SetOutLineWidth(width);
    }

    public void SetOutLineWidth(float width)
    {
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Outline", width);
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeOutline()
    {
        float timeToWait = 3f;

        while (currentWidth < width)
        {
            width += 0.01f;
            SetOutLineWidth(width);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is for example if I will set width variable value to 5 then change the value until the currentWidth is 5:

```
SetOutLineWidth(width);
```

If the currentWidth is 7 and I set width to 5 change the value from 7 to 5 slowly. If currentWidth is 7 and I set width to 10 again change it slowly to 10.
What I did now is making the width value keep raising and setting the Outline non stop.

What I want to do in general is to make two modes:

1. Change the width value and set the Outline slowly according to the time once on one direction.
2. Like 1 but make it ping pong mode once the outline value reached to width change it back slowly to the first value outline was and then back to width nonstop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do (based, on your description) is to lerp between 2 numbers.

No need for timer, just do this:

```
public float duration = 3f;
float lerp = 0;

public float currentWidth = 4;
public float finalWidth = 10;


private void Update()
{
    lerp += Time.deltaTime / duration;
    currentWidth = Mathf.Lerp(currentWidth, finalWidth, lerp);

    SetOutLineWidth(currentWidth);
}

public void SetOutLineWidth(float w)
{
    rend.material.SetFloat("_Outline", w);
}
```

Unity Lerp documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what material you are using, so I just changed the script to use the scale of a plane object, but you can attach any shape to it.  You should be able to modify the script to make it work with the material property.

```
using UnityEngine;

public enum Mode
{
    Grow,
    Shrink,
    PingPong
}

public class Outline : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxWidth;
public float minWidth;
public float growthRate;
public float timeToWait = 1f;
public Mode Mode;

private float currentWidth;
private bool grow = false;
private float timeToUpdate;

private void Update()
{
    currentWidth = transform.localScale.x;
    if (Time.time + timeToWait > timeToUpdate)
    {
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case Mode.Grow:
                if (currentWidth < maxWidth)
                {
                    currentWidth += growthRate;
                    SetOutLineWidth(currentWidth);
                }

                break;
            case Mode.Shrink:
                if (currentWidth > minWidth)
                {
                    currentWidth -= growthRate;
                    SetOutLineWidth(currentWidth);

                }

                break;
            case Mode.PingPong:

                if (grow)
                {
                    currentWidth += growthRate;
                    SetOutLineWidth(currentWidth);
                   if (currentWidth >= maxWidth)
                       grow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentWidth -= growthRate;
                    SetOutLineWidth(currentWidth);
                   if (currentWidth <= minWidth)
                        grow = true;

                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        timeToUpdate = Time.time + timeToWait;
    }
}

public void SetOutLineWidth(float width)
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(width, 1, 1);
}
}
```